# programmatically added button should move to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have programmatically generated buttons like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int y = 127;
    for (int i=0; i<=6; i++) {
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      //[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      button.frame = CGRectMake(26, y, 268, 41);
      [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button-%i", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cys_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn" size:21]];
      [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:60/255.0 green:60/255.0 blue:60/255.0 alpha:1]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
      button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 15, 0, 0);

      [scrollViewContent addSubview:button];
      y=y+43;
    }
}
```

and method which shows text after click:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    int y = 127;
    int i = 6;

    for (int x=0; x<=i; x++) {
      NSString *frameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{{26, %i}, {268, 41}}", y];
      if ([NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame) isEqualToString:frameString])  {
        NSLog(@"button %i clicked..", x);
      }
      y= y+43;
  } 
}
```

How to do that after click the button transfer occurred to the next view?

Comment: use tag property to identify your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
button.tag=i;
```

set tag to the button while creating button in `viewDidLoad` so that you can identify your button by using the tag above.

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
```